# install vim for all users

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-18.04

I've cloned and then compiled vim using this guide:
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

After running configure I ran

```
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim81
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```

After running that sequence of commands, vim was installed only for the root user. To have vim available for the current user I had to run

```
make install
```

Why "sudo make install" didn't install vim for the current user? How can I fix the fact that now I've probably two vims installed? Thanks

Comment: Why not just `apt-get install vim`?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Vim building but normally the target installation directory (/usr, /opt...) is a compilation/build option (search for a `--prefix` in the configuration utilities...).